# What exactly is '$' symbol in gradle used for in dependencies?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have cloned a repository that contains api "com.github.xxx:$yyy_zzz". I understand that the $ symbol captures the latest build or version of the project. But when I try to use it in my own project, the gradle build says that Could not get unknown property 'yyy_zzz'. What should I do to implement it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$variable_name` is a variable declared and exported.

in your `project` `build.gradle` do the follow:

```
buildscript {
    ext.support_version = '27.1.1'
    ...
}
```

and then, in your `app` `build.gradle` file, you can declare dependencies like this:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$support_version"
    ...
}
```